# Django File chunks() not returning full binary file

Tags: python

In Django I am trying to use FileField on my model and set that using a existing file on the filesystem. I tried this and I was only getting 10s of KBs in the media directory.

```
c = MyClass()
f = open('D:\\bin.jpg')
df = File(file)
c.file.save('newFile', df)
f.close()
c.save()
```

FileField.save calls File.chunks and it looks like for binary files it not getting the whole thing. Am I missing something here?

```
f_text = File(open('D:\\text.txt'))
print f_text.size / 1024. / 1024
>> 13.7466430664
print sum([len(c) for c in f_text.chunks()]) / 1024. / 1024
>> 13.7466430664

f_bin = File(open('D:\\bin.jpg'))
print f_bin.size / 1024. / 1024
>> 0.741801261902
print sum([len(c) for c in f_bin.chunks()]) / 1024. / 1024
>> 0.00253677368164

f = MyClass.objects.get(id=50).file
# is file as f_bin uploaded using Django admin tool
print f.size / 1024. / 1024
>> 0.741801261902
print sum([len(c) for c in f.chunks()]) / 1024. / 1024
>> 0.741801261902
```

System: Windows 7

Django: 1.5.1

Python: 2.7.5

Comment: This is not a Django question, it's a Python question.  The tags should be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode:

```
f_bin = File(open('D:\\bin.jpg', 'rb'))
```

See [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the Python documentation.